# How $|\mathbb R|$ is not weakly compact

Tags: set-theory, examples-counterexamples, large-cardinals

$\mathbb R$, of cardinality $|\mathbb R|=2^{\aleph_0}$ is not weakly compact.

So there is a function $f$ from $[{\mathbb R}]^2$ (the subsets of $\mathbb R$ of size 2) to $\{0,1\}$ such that there is **no** $X\subset \mathbb R$ of cardinality $|\mathbb R|$, such that $f$ is constant on $[X]^2$.

I know, by the infinite Ramsey's theorem that there is no such function if I use $\mathbb N$ instead of $\mathbb R$, but
how do you build such a function $f$ for $\mathbb R$ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that being weakly compact is not synonymous with "having the tree property", but rather it is synonymous with "having the tree property **and** being inaccessible". Note that $2^{\aleph_0}$ is never a strong limit cardinal, so the latter must fail and $2^{\aleph_0}$ cannot be a weakly compact cardinal.

The continuum can be almost weakly compact, though, meaning it may still have the tree property. This, of course, requires the consistency strength of a weakly compact cardinal to begin with. Of course this means that $2^{\aleph_0}>\aleph_1$, since $\sf ZFC$ proves that $\aleph_1$ doesn't have the tree property.

You can find references in both these papers:

> 1. William Mitchell, **[Aronszajn trees and the independence of the transfer property](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0003-4843(72)90017-4)**, *Annals of Mathematical Logic*, Volume **5**, Issue 1, Dec. 1972, pp. 21-46.
> 2. Uri Abraham, **[Aronszajn trees on $\aleph_2$ and $\aleph_3$](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0168-0072(83)90006-4)**, *Annals of Pure and Applied Logic*, Volume **24**, Issue 3, Sep. 1983, pp 213-230.

Comment: Thanks ! So this means that wikipedia is false by stating that a weakly compact cardinal is an uncountable cardinal with the tree property ?! http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weakly_compact_cardinal. Or the existence of $f$ is stronger than the tree property ?

Comment: That's not what Wikipedia is saying. It says that for an uncountable $\kappa$ it is equivalent to say that it is weakly compact if and only if it is inaccessible and has the tree property.

Comment: second paragraph : Formally, a cardinal κ is defined to be weakly compact if it is uncountable and for every function ...

Comment: Oh yeah, that one. You can prove that the existence of such $f$ implies that $\kappa$ is inaccessible.

Comment: So, that was my initial question, how do you exhibit such a function that does not work ?

Comment: Suppose that $\lambda<\kappa$ is the first cardinal such that $\kappa\leq2^\lambda$. Let $\{A_\alpha\subseteq\lambda\mid\alpha<\kappa\}$, and define $\alpha\prec\beta\iff\min(A_\alpha\triangle A_\beta)\in A_\beta$. For $\alpha<\beta$ we define $f(\alpha,\beta)=1$ if and only if $\alpha\prec\beta$ (since $f$ is a function on unordered pairs, it suffices). Suppose $S$ is a homogeneous set of size $\kappa$, then $\langle \alpha\mid\alpha\in S\rangle$ is either a strictly increasing or a strictly decreasing sequence in $\prec$, from which you can define an injection form $\kappa$ into $\lambda$.

Comment: You can also find the details in Jech's **Set Theory** (3rd Millennium Edition) on Chapter 9, Lemma 9.4, 9.5 and Theorem 9.9.

Comment: תודה רבה ! Now, it's clear for me. So I need AC to have a good order on $\mathbb R$ to build such a function.

Comment: Xoff, the axiom of choice plays a role in many things here. I didn't even begin to mention it. It is consistent that $\aleph_1$ has the tree property, and in such model the continuum is not even close to being well-ordered. That besides the point, trees are naturally related to the ordinals (i.e. the levels are well-ordered). How would you define a tree of height $2^{\aleph_0}$ is $2^{\aleph_0}$ is not an ordinal?

Comment: I just use cardinality of $\mathbb R$ in my question (the first line was just an introduction). It exists without AC (even if it's not some $\aleph$). So I was not sure if AC was really necessary to define the problematic function, as you just need to show some contradiction by making an injection from a power set to the initial set (it's what you do if I say $\lambda=\mathbb N$ and $\kappa=\mathbb R$, but with AC).

Comment: For example, define a bijection $b$ from $\mathbb R$ to ${\mathcal P}(\mathbb N)$ (you don't need AC). and for $x<y$ (usual order on $\mathbb R$) define f(x,y)=1 iff $b(x)\prec b(y)$ (using the order you defined in comments). Doesn't it work too ?

Comment: I don't know to answer that from the hip. Jech's proof uses the fact that we are indexing everything with ordinals, but if $\aleph_1\nleq2^{\aleph_0}$ then we can't use this fact. It might be the case that in some models $2^{\aleph_0}$ has this partition principle, I'll have to think about it further -- but it's a great question.